# How do I access files in the iPhone Simulators "Files app"?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I saved a file on the iOS simulator to the Files App. Specifically, I chose to save into "On My iPhone" > Downloads.

Where can I find this file in Finder on macOS?

I found `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/UUID/data/Downloads` but that folder is empty even though when I launch the Files app in my simulator, I clearly see files in the Downloads directory.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find it by doing a search within the /UUID folder. Apparently files saved to the Downloads folder in the Files app are saved to:

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/UUID/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/UUID/File Provider Storage/Downloads/
```

Comment: The first UUID in the path and the second UUID are different - the first one is a simulator UUID and the second one is of the file provider. You need to search for a folder "File Provider Storage"

Comment: This doesn't appear to be up to date